# Java Searlize a Window Component in String and save in DB?

Tags: java, serialization, zk

I am using ZK Framework i want to serialize Window component or Window Object in String and save into the database and again get it from database and deserialize  it  . How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.wikihow.com/Serialize-an-Object-in-Java

```
public class AbstractComponent implements Component, ComponentCtrl, java.io.Serializable
```

Greetz chill.

Comment: I do it how to restore the state of Window

Comment: Get your window in your VM/controller. window = your object retrieved and invalidate it.